# Selectpicker (bootstrap-select) doesn't work, shows a disabled menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to use selectpicker from Bootstrap-Select to make a multi-select dropdown menu. Here is what I have in my HTML file:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

But this is what I get on my web app:

[image]

I can't hit the dropdown menu, it's disabled. How do I get this menu to be enabled?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/u628skn1/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Did you include the javascript file? If using CDN or download it, please make sure to include jquery, bootstrap, and the bootstrap-select. Once set up correctly, with the selectpicker class to your select elements, it will   auto-initialize bootstrap-select.

2) If to style only custom class, use:

```
$('.my-custom').selectpicker();
```

Comment: When you say javascript file, do you mean a <script> tag for bootstrap-select.min.js? If so, then yes. Also, I tried putting in that code, but I'm not sure where it goes; do I put that in a script tag at the head of the HTML document?

Comment: No, you don't have to initialize it via javascript. You can do it via selectpicker class. It will automatically initialize the dropdown: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Where do I put the code? I put it within the <head> tag but nothing has changed, the selectpicker is still disabled.

Comment: which way you your code, Install via CDN? are you just using a pure html file?

Comment: I'm not using CDN, I downloaded "bootstrap-select.min.css" and "bootstrap-select.min.css" locally (along with bootstrap, jQuery, popper, etc.) I'm starting to think I didn't set up my links to these files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you question is already answered, but a snippet might help ?

```js
$(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-CjSoeELFOcH0/uxWu6mC/Vlrc1AARqbm/jiiImDGV3s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. When you're grabbing Bootstrap.js, jQuery, and Popper for your HTML file, they *have* to be in this order:

`<script src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"> 
 <script src="popper.min.js">
 <script src="bootstrap.min.js">`

Or else certain things won't work. Once I changed this, selectpicker worked fine.